# How to use the grid() python

Tags: python, grid, tkinter

How can I use the `grid()` to place a widget at the bottom of a window? For example, this code will place these labels right under each other, but what if I want to move label_4 to the bottom of the window, or closer to the bottom, how is this accomplished?

```
label_1 = Label(text = 'Name 1').grid(row = 0, sticky = W)
label_2 = Label(text = 'Name 2').grid(row = 1, sticky = W)
label_3 = Label(text = 'Name 3').grid(row = 2, sticky = W)
label_4 = Label(text = 'Name 4').grid(row = 3, sticky = W)
```

Comment: Note that `grid` returns `None`, so with your code `label_1` ... `label_4` will all be `None`. If you want the `label` variable to reference  `Label`s, then you must call `label.grid` as a separate statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the grid system for this, you have to create a "spacer" cell in the grid system (an empty one), which can dynamically get the spaces left from the window, and pushes the last label to the bottom.

```
from Tkinter import *  # or tkinter if you use Python3

root = Tk()

label_1 = Label(master=root, text='Name 1')
label_2 = Label(master=root, text='Name 2')
label_3 = Label(master=root, text='Name 3')
label_4 = Label(master=root, text='Name 4')

label_1.grid(row=0)
label_2.grid(row=1)
label_3.grid(row=2)  # this is the 2nd
label_4.grid(row=4)  # this is the 4th

root.rowconfigure(index=3, weight=1)  # add weight to the 3rd!
root.mainloop()
```

But for this simple scenario, I think you should use `pack` instead of `grid`:

```
from Tkinter import *  # or tkinter if you use Python3

root = Tk()

label_1 = Label(master=root, text='Name 1')
label_2 = Label(master=root, text='Name 2')
label_3 = Label(master=root, text='Name 3')
label_4 = Label(master=root, text='Name 4')

label_1.pack()
label_2.pack()
label_3.pack()
label_4.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to actually put something in that spacer; you can just do `root.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)` and that row will take up all the slack.

Comment: Sure, but in that case, the last label won't stick to the bottom in a fixed position. Although your version could be useful for the OP, since he asked: *" to the bottom of the window, or closer to the bottom"*. Thanks for your reflection.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comments. If you put a label on row **4**, and then configure row **3** (with nothing in it) to have a positive weight, the label in row 4 _will_ stick to the bottom.

Comment: Yes, I did misunderstand you, sorry — you version is much nicer, I fixed mine! Thanks again!

Comment: It may help to put something like `root.geometry("100x300+200+200")` in there to make it more obvious that there is space in between `label_3` and `label_4`.

Comment: I'm glad we could help!